# Notification service extension for Local notification

Tags: swift, notifications, ios10, uilocalnotification, serviceextension

will system loads Notification service extension and calls its `didReceive(_:withContentHandler:)` for local notifications in iOS 10?
If yes how we can do that?

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/ios10-user-notifications-guide/

Comment: The accepted answer here appears to be wrong.

Answer (score 11):

No. The accepted answer describes Notification *Content* Extensions, which allow you to present a ViewController in the expanded notification view, and works with both remote and local notification.

Notification *Service* Extensions, that let you change the content of the notification (attaching images, etc) do **not** work with local notifications. However, you can attach images as part of the process to show a local notification.

Comment: Do you by chance have a documentation or WWDC talk link to confirm that this is not possible?

Comment: I don't, sorry. This is just my personal experience.

Answer (score 2):

Notification Service extension is for remote notification not for local notification.

[As per apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension)

UNNotificationServiceExtension
An object that modifies the content of a *remote notification* before it's delivered to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Notification Content Extension for displaying custom notification with iOS10. In the Xcode menu bar, go to File->New->Target. Then from the list select Notification Content Extension.
[image]

Enter the corresponding details and click Finnish. You will see a new folder with the name of your extension. In the folder, there will be 3 files :

1. NotificationViewController : Here you can design your custom interface and implement responses.
2. MainStoryboard : You can use this to design your custom notification.
3. Info.plist

In the Info.plist file, add the following:
[image]

This will be the category identifier you will use in your main project when scheduling notifications.

```
let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "myNotificationCategory", actions: [], intentIdentifiers:[], options: [])
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
            content.categoryIdentifier = "myNotificationCategory"
```

Your NotificationViewController class should look something like this.

```
func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
        //change properties of notification here.
    }

    func didReceive(_ response: UNNotificationResponse, completionHandler completion: @escaping (UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption) -> Void) {
        //implement response logic here.
    }
```

There are a couple of good tutorials available online. You can check [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-10-creating-custom-notification-interfaces--cms-27251), [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-10-notification-service-extensions--cms-27550) & [here](https://www.appcoda.com/ios10-user-notifications-guide/).
Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd also like to make it clear that the question was whether or not you can use the Notice Service Extension for Local notifications. Well, yes you can.

Comment: @Morgz I think that we cannot use notification service extension for local notification.

Answer (score -1):

Notification Extension is supported for local notifications too. It is clearly mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension)

**UNNotificationContentExtension
An object that presents a custom interface for a delivered local or remote notification.**

Comment: It's different from NotificationServiceExtension, but still helpful