# how to set mutable-content key in UNMutableNotificationContent?

Tags: swift3, notifications, ios10, localnotification

I need to simulate notification with mutable-content on simulator to use service extension.I am unable to find a way to set mutable-content in UNMutableNotificationContent. is there is any way to set it or it supposed to be work like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `mutable-content` is not supported in local UNNotification, as seen in [Notification service extension for Local notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378842/notification-service-extension-for-local-notification)